# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have updated my Firebase packages.

```
firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  cloud_functions: ^0.6.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.4+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
```

After updating I am getting this error.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20050): The following FirebaseException was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<FeedbackAnswer>(value:
I/flutter (20050): <not yet loaded>):
I/flutter (20050): [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

After using

```
Firebase.initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions(
    appId: 'xyzzy',
    projectId: 'zzzz',
    apiKey: 'zzzz',
    messagingSenderId: 'zzz',
  ),name: "Rapport");
```

I am getting 2 errors
First is

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20050): The following FirebaseException was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<FeedbackAnswer>(value:
I/flutter (20050): <not yet loaded>):
I/flutter (20050): [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

Second is warning I guess

```
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(20050): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
I/flutter (20050): firebase_crashlytics: Error reported to Crashlytics.
E/flutter (20050): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "Rapport" already exists
E/flutter (20050): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:97:7)
```

Please help me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you already imported `GoogleService-Info.plist` as described in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)
additionally, plz try `flutter clean` and launch again in a simulator or phone.